# Unable to create record with GENERATED IDENTITY primary key using Ebean

Tags: java, oracle, ebean

I have a table in Oracle Database 12c, created with the following DDL:

```
create table customer (
  id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(100)
);
```

I am trying to insert a row to this table using [Ebean.save](http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/persist/#saves) method with the model defined below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

  @Id
  Integer id;
  ....
```

The code used to insert the row is as follows:

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.setName(name);
Ebean.save(customer);
```

It is failing with the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1054)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623)
  ....

Caused by: Error : 2289, Position : 7, Sql = select 
  customer_seq.nextval, a from (select level as a FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 20), OriginalSql = select customer_seq.nextval, a from (select level as a FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 20), Error Msg = ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
```

From the error, what I understand is that Ebean is trying to use `Sequence` strategy for the identity column and it is failing. I've tried setting `Identity` strategy as follows without any success, maybe because Ebean is using `Sequence` strategy for Oracle DB as explained [here](http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/mapping/jpa/id#database-platform).

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
Integer id;
```

Is there a way to save a row in a Oracle 12c table with autogenerated identity column as defined above with Ebean? Was I on the right track by setting the `IDENTITY` strategy?

Comment: I don't know Ebean or Java, but the error refers to `customer.nextval` which doesn't exist, hence `ORA-02289: sequence does not exist`. Where does `customer.nextval` come from? The `insert` (which isn't shown) needs to skip that column entirely and let it default.

Comment: That was a typo occurred while posting the question, I have updated the it accordingly. It was in fact a sequence name related to the table that Ebean is trying to access, which does not exist.

Comment: My comment still applies though. Now it’s `customer_seq.nextval`, which is still wrong whether it exists or not. However, your error message refers to a `select` statement but your question is about inserting, so I’m not sure exactly what needs to change.

Comment: I belive that it's an internal query issued by Ebean to get the identity column value. I've updated the question to include the code snippet that tries to insert the row.

Comment: Not my area but the `new/save` logic looks OK. However according to the [Ebean documentation](http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/mapping/jpa/id) I found, _"All the supported databases use either Identity or Sequences (or allow both) and Ebean will choose the appropriate Id generation strategy based on the database platform."_ In the list it has "Sequences" next to Oracle. Maybe they haven't updated it for Oracle 12.1 yet?

Comment: Yes, it looks like that. I was wondering whether there is a way to override the Id generation strategy, and whether setting it to `IDENTITY` will solve the issue.

Comment: Try creating your identity column as BY DEFAULT rather than ALWAYS

Comment: `BY DEFAULT` option also does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Ebean, and is fixed in [11.10.1](https://github.com/ebean-orm/ebean/releases/tag/ebean-11.10.1) release. The [bug](https://github.com/ebean-orm/ebean/issues/1243) was reported on github following my [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ebean/Hyh9hFRv4aY) on Ebean's google group. I have verified that I can specify autogenerated identity column with this version of Ebean as follows:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
Integer id;
```